# Wordpress site not logging in

Tags: wordpress, authentication, admin, wordpress-login

I created a site locally on my machine everything is working fine, I uploaded it to my server a couple of weeks ago for testing/client review.

Everything looked good so the site was launch. The sites been up and running fine for about a month, today I tried to login to the backend but I have'nt been able to.

I'm able to access the login page fine. I insert my username and password and the page does nothing, just refreshes the page and clears the login form. I've tried resetting my admin password using the login form and it just keeps telling my to input a username or email.

I've downloaded the entire site and database installed it locally and it runs great no issues. I've up graded the local version to 3.1.3 it was still working fine so I replaced the live version with the new files, and still no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do people upvote non-programming questions?

Comment: did you try requesting your password by clicking on "Lost your password"?

Comment: Yes, does nothing but ask for the username or email over and over.

Comment: so what happens if you supply an email? it doesn't send you any email? if so, you may need to use phpmyadmin & look at wp_users table & check if it has the correct email & username, but don't try to change password because it's encrypted.

Comment: Do you have a recent databse backup that you could restore if anything else fails?

Comment: when I supply an email it just asks for the email again nothing is sent. I've checked the database and it is the correct email.

Comment: I've downloaded the latest version of the database and used it in a local version of the site I'm running with out any issues at all.

Comment: Still running into issues... I've taken my local copy of the site that is running fine and uploaded it and the database, and I'm still running into the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not 100% sure what caused the problem, I'm guessing something in the core wordpress install was corrupted.

I ended up installing a fresh version of wordpress, exporting and then importing my database into a new database, and uploading the media, theme, and plugins separately which seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a duplicate of a site on localhost or dev server and they have the same security keys it can cause a cookie collision.

Make a change to all of the security keys in the wp-config.php file and it will reset all sessions and cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me and i already mentioned here what worked for me.

[Wordpress 3.8 gives me "You must enable cookies to use WordPress." at login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093541/wordpress-3-8-gives-me-you-must-enable-cookies-to-use-wordpress-at-login/22420931#22420931)